# Seed to java.security.SecureRandom on Windows os

Tags: java, windows, random, seed, secure-random

I am interested in `java.util.Random` and `java.security.SecureRandom` classes. I found that `Random` uses system clock to generate seed and `SecureRandom` uses `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` but these files are on Linux, while on Windows it uses some mistic `CryptGenRandom`. Even if that is super secure function, do we know from where does it take values? What is the basement to generate seed?

Comment: It's a [windows native function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptGenRandom), not strictly related to java. You'll need to dig into Microsoft docs to find the answer I think.

Comment: You might find this post of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119751/java-keytool-the-security-of-generated-keys-with-java-in-general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class java.security.[SecureRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) Uses the system API provided by the OS host. Each OS has their own process to generate random numbers.

In Windows [SecureRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) uses the method [CryptGenRandom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenrandom) that is part of WinCrypt Windows library (Included in Advapi32.dll of Windows System libraries).

All the documentation about the Windows function is available in the Microsoft docs of [CryptGenRandom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenrandom)

Comment: oke, thanks! That's what I was looking for:
`To form the seed for the random number generator, a calling application supplies bits it might have—for instance, mouse or keyboard timing input—that are then combined with both the stored seed and various system data and user data such as the process ID and thread ID, the system clock, the system time, the system counter, memory status, free disk clusters, the hashed user environment block. This result is used to seed the pseudorandom number generator (PRNG).`